# "The private attribute may be used only on class property definitions." FlashDevelop + Adobe Flex SDK + Debug_nape.swc

Tags: actionscript-3

There's already a question on this, but it doesn't exactly answer my question, as I'm very new to flash.  When I compile my code, it gives me an error on line 69+74, on the 'p' in the two 'private's.
here's the code:

```
    private function destroyMouseJoint(e:MouseEvent):void 
{
    hand.active = false;
}

private function spawnBox():void 
{
    var block:Polygon = new Polygon(Polygon.box(50, 50));
    var body:Body = new Body(BodyType.DYNAMIC);
    body.shapes.add(block);
    body.position.setxy(stage.stageWidth /2, stage.height / 2);
    body.space = space;
}
```

I'm not sure what I'm supposed to do.  Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you might be putting you function outside the class definition.  Make sure they are in something like the following:

```
package  {
import flash.display.Sprite;

public class YourClass extends Sprite {
            private var bg:Sprite;

            public function YourClass() {
                super();
            }

            private function destroyMouseJoint(e:MouseEvent):void {
                hand.active = false;
            }

            private function spawnBox():void  {
                var block:Polygon = new Polygon(Polygon.box(50, 50));
                var body:Body = new Body(BodyType.DYNAMIC);
                body.shapes.add(block);
                body.position.setxy(stage.stageWidth /2, stage.height / 2);
                body.space = space;
            }
      }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks!  Turns out the private functions were outside of the public class.